# PyGame on Raspberry Pi 2: Faster loading than pygame.image.load() possible?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, image-manipulation, raspberry-pi2

I started to play around a bit with PyGame and I wrote a slideshow for showing images fullscreen on my Raspberry Pi 2.

Everything is working fine, except that loading files takes (in my opinion) far too long.

The images I used for testing are locally stored on the RPi 2, `4608x3456` in dimension and about `3MB` in size.

Following code (MCVE) is used for loading a file (only one is loaded at a time):

```
start_loading_time = time.time()
img = pygame.image.load(file)
elapsed_loading_time = time.time() - start_loading_time
print("Image loading took {}s".format(elapsed_loading_time))
```

which returns on average a loading time of 2.8 seconds.

I know that the RPi 2 has to load everything from a SD card, but I think this is still a very long loading time for a `3MB` image.

Is there anything I can do about the loading time except pre-processing the images with some tool to reduce their resoluting, resulting in smaller images?

Comment: I would be interested to see if you got significantly improved load times by tiling all your images into one very large image and loading it all at once, and then use `Surface.subsurface` (along with some metadata from another file perhaps?) to split it up. If it is taking a long time to initialize something in the sd card drivers or something, but not the actual loading this might help. If it is the actual read times I can't see how doing anything but using lower res images (and then if you wanted `pygame.transform.smoothscale`)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are trying to avoid a wait between slides, you should pre-load all of your images in the loading phase before you begin attempting to show them, or make each slide last longer than the image loading time, so load the next image during that time where nothing else is happening.